# Build the Node js app on Docker

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

I was trying to run the below docker file

```
FROM node:latest

VOLUME /data

COPY package.json /data/
WORKDIR /data
RUN npm install

COPY . /data/

ENTRYPOINT ["npm", "run", "nodeApp"]
```

I was able to build the project without any errors, but while running it throws node module not found error.

**update**: It throws, 'json-server' not found exception at index.js file

My package structure is as follows,

```
data
   db.json
Dockerfile
index.js
package.json
```

Package.json file is as follows,

```
{
      "name": "node-api",
      "version": "0.0.1",
      "main": "index.js",
      "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "nodeApp": "node index.js data/db.json"
      },
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "dependencies": {
        "json-server": "^0.8.2",
        "lowdb": "^0.10.2",
        "node-uuid": "^1.4.7"
      }
    }
```

UPDATE: 
index.js file

```
"use strict";
var jsonServer = require('json-server');
var low = require('lowdb');
var uuid = require('node-uuid');

var fs = require('fs');
var db = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(process.argv[2]));
var writeDb = low(process.argv[2]);

var server = jsonServer.create();
server.use(jsonServer.defaults());

var router = jsonServer.router(db);
router.db._.id = 'id';

router.render = function (req, res) {
  return enhance(req, res);
};

server.use('/api', router);
server.use(router);
server.listen(8081);

function enhance(req, res) {
 return res.jsonp(res.locals.data); // do no processing
}
```

Comment: Dockerfile looks fine.can you show your package.json file

Comment: Can you post the error message? Could be that you are using a dependency thats not in package.json

Comment: @elssar I have updated the question with the error info.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing what your `index.js` is doing

Answer (score 0):

Based on your `package.json` and project structure

1. The entrypoint should be `["npm", "run", "payments-api"]`
2. `payments-api` should be `node index.js values/db.json`

**EDIT**:

Its hard to tell based on the information provided, but

1. Could be that `json-server` is not being required in `index.js`
2. You're tying to call the `json-server` command in `index.js`, but since its not installed globally, it can't be found

Comment: do we need to install the npm modules gobally?

Comment: I have added index.js file

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are copying data into a volume after running npm install.
I guess the COPY will override your installation.
To confirm.

Also, COPY all your data into the container is not a good practice.
You will need to rebuild your container each time you update your source code.

I Suggest you something like that :

```
FROM node:latest

RUN mkdir -p /src
WORKDIR /src

ADD package.json /src/package.json
RUN npm install;

EXPOSE 8081
VOLUME ./:/src/
CMD npm nodeApp
```

or

```
CMD node /src/index.js
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your suggestion, but I dont understand what does this mean 'COPY all your data into the container is not a goof practice'?

Comment: I updated my answer tu reflect your app. If you COPY your directory into the container, you will have to rebuild your container each time you modify a file. You should you a VOLUME instead.